# How to make an html page open automatically on a CD/DVD

Tags: html, dvd, cd

I need to include an html page (table of contents) on a CD/DVD.  I'd like the html page to open automatically when the user puts the CD/DVD in their machine.  Is there a way to do this (the MSDN cds do this) either by purchasing software or otherwise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used (the free version of) [AutoRunPro](http://www.longtion.com/autorunpro/autorunpro.htm)

I remember when I was confronted with the problem once

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=path\to\htmlfile.html
```

just wouldn't work on most PC's.  I used a program called AutorunPro.EXE, just copied it in the root, and the autorun.inf was :

```
[Autorun]
open=AutoRunPro.exe

[AutorunPro]
; Here are some sample uses for Autorunpro. It keeps processing Them in Run1..RunN         order until it doesnt find one.
Run1=index.htm
Run2=.
```

Moreover, you can open several programs, pages, ... with this method in one go.

In either case : test your method beforehand, you don't actually have to burn a CD/DVD in order to do that : 
[look here](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/windows/howtotcdaurwobacd.htm)

Answer (score 16):

You should be able to do with a relatively simple `autorun.inf` file in the CD/DVD's root directory:

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=path\to\htmlfile.html
```

Comment: I have just burned a DVD using the above and it works.  I used index.html which was in the root of the DVD: shellexecute=index.html

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to trust to third party programs, or skip over them entirely you can read the [MSDN AutoRun Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136610(VS.85).aspx). It's not too bad.

Answer (score 2):

[ShelExec](http://www.naughter.com/shelexec.html) is your ticket.  It is free and allows you to specify an optional ico file too.

Answer (score 0):

It's dead simple. I use a program called Autorun Pro. Check out [this guide](http://www.ezau.com/latest/articles/autorun.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple executable yourself. In Visual Studio in example.

Not sure it can be call one-liner but it is not far from it :-)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "Shellapi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "path\to\htmlfile.html", 0, 0, SW_NORMAL);
    return 0;
}
```

To avoid hard-coding you can try passing path as a parameter in command line.

autorun file must be added to the CD. File can look like this.

```
[autorun]
icon=\MySexyIcon.ico
label=MySuperCD
open=YourExecutable.exe
```

Please bear in mind that it will not work on iOS though.