# How do I open a directory using Html when the files and html are all on a DVD

Tags: html

I work for a large company with agents all over the U.S.  We want to upgrade our agents to Open Source office suite (Apache Open Office) from the chaotic mismatch of different versions used now.  Problem is many of our people are barely computer literate.

I need to build a menu in Html to install the proper version on their systems from a DVD I have downloaded the files onto.

I can code some Html and some java but not a lot.  It would help if it were cross browser since some use Macs but most use PCs.

I have researched for days and find many references to no access from the Web bit surely there is a way to do it offline?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What you can do is that you open the files with javascript. use Jquery for this with their `load()` attribute or use javascript. for the path to the files you can try a path like `E://path/to/file`

Comment: Why do you need a "menu in Html"? If you are going to make them go into the DVD to open a menu, it seems pointless when they can just double-click the install.exe on your DVD that you burned the files onto.

Comment: Here is a related question asking how to open a html file automatically when the DVD is inserted in the drive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735412/how-to-make-an-html-page-open-automatically-on-a-cd-dvd?rq=1

Comment: Just be aware that any solution relying on AutoRun will not work if it is disabled.  This is not uncommon since AutoRun is used as a malware attack vector.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that HTML is really what you want here.  HTML is used to create web pages, but it's not a programming language and is not well suited to executing commands or performing tasks.  JavaScript is the most common programming language used in web browsers, but you will have problems accessing a user's local file system for security reasons.

The best option I can think of is to give the installers appropriate names based on OS, and include documentation that clearly explains to users what they need to do.  HTML may or may not be suitable for the documentation depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you for those suggestions.  I currently know nothing about Mac Os, and I was trying to find a way that both PC users and Mac users could at least open a description of the location of the files, as well as make it easy for those that are I'm afraid computer Dumb.  Since I know that the web is accessed by both, I concluded it might be the obvious answer.  Is there another type of file that can be opened by both formats?

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everyone for their help.

Do to time restraints I believe the fastest solution is to do a simple text document in several forms describing the file choices and links to the files.

This way may not be eloquent but it is efficient.

Thanks for your time.