# cd/dvd autorun.inf IE setup to open web doc

Tags: autorun

I have basic `autorun.inf` setup, which opens IE on client machine then tries to open html document located on cd/dvd within just opened IE.

Here it is:

```
open="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" index.html
```

Is it possible to pass somehow global variable or any other shortcut to lets say  Program Files? It will be awesome if I could be sure that if user have different directories structure, still autorun will find out and open IE instead of doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[autorun]
open=start filepathname\index.html
```

Comment: Add some context to your code to help future readers better understand its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a question that looks like the answer you are looking for, please take a look:

[How to make an html page open automatically on a CD/DVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735412/how-to-make-an-html-page-open-automatically-on-a-cd-dvd)

Hope it helps.