# How to run my html file in cd / dvd?

Tags: html, cd, autorun, dvd

I want to save my html file to a cd / dvd, and if the cd is inserted to the PC, the html file should be automatically open in a browser without pressing any button.

I hope anyone can help me with this, thanks a lot.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an html page open automatically on a CD/DVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735412/how-to-make-an-html-page-open-automatically-on-a-cd-dvd)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create autorun.inf file in the root of cd and then you need to add parameters to this file.

The limitation is that not every operating system will allow you to open documents. It is meant to sun exe files.

If you write something like this in autorun.inf it will work only on some versions of Windows OS:

```
[autorun]
open=start index.html
```

Here is an article with explanations:
http://www.autoruntools.com/autorun-inf.php

Answer (score 0):

create autorun.inf file in the CD's root directory:

and add following :

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=path\index.html
```